# Prove $ \| {\bf A}^2\|_* \leq \operatorname{tr}({\bf A}^\dagger {\bf A})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, svd, nuclear-norm

I saw a lemma without any proof states that:

$$ \left\| {\bf A}^2 \right\|_* \leq \operatorname{tr} \left( {\bf A}^\dagger {\bf A} \right)$$

where $\bf A$ is an arbitrary square matrix and $\|\cdot\|_*$ denotes the [nuclear norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms) (Schatten 1-norm).

I tried many inequalities related to the nuclear norm, but most of them only show what a nuclear norm is larger than.​ I can't prove it.​

Comment: It follows directly from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$\|A^2\|_\ast=\max\limits_{Q\in U_n}|\operatorname{tr}(A^2Q)|=\max\limits_{Q\in U_n}|\langle A^\dagger,AQ\rangle_F|\le\max\limits_{Q\in U_n}\|A^\dagger\|_F\|AQ\|_F=\|A\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger A).$$

Comment: @user1551 That looks like a good answer to me.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2831001/339790)

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2397442/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Not really? I mean, these do involve nuclear and Frobenius norms as well, but that's pretty much where it stops.

Comment: @ClementC. Hence, "somewhat".  Only need to be more related than the (randomly chosen?) ones in the `Related` column on the RHS of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$
\| A^2\|_\ast = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(A^2) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(A)^2 = \operatorname{Tr}(A^\dagger A)
$$

where the inequality follows from the more general lemma (for $A=B$, $m=n=k=r$ and $p=1$):

**Lemma.** (Theorem 3.3.14 in [1]) Let $p>0$, and $A,B$ be two $n\times k$ and $k\times m$ matrices, respectively. Then, for any $r \leq \min(n,k,m)$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{r} \sigma_i(AB)^p \leq \sum_{i=1}^{r} \sigma_i(A)^p\sigma_i(B)^p
$$

[1] R. A. Horn and C. R. Johnson. *Topics in Matrix Analysis.* Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1991.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, it was a problem in my recent exercise that reminded me of this question. It seems not easy to prove the theorem in the textbook. I will take a clolser look at this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

OK. After learning about Frobenius norm, I found a proof which is more simple than what has shown in the reference involved in the answer of @Clement C. This answer is from @user1551 and includes more detail.

**Definition.** For $A, B \in C^{m\times n}$, we can define Frobenius inner product (Hilbert-Schmidt inner product):
$$\langle A, B\rangle_F=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}^*B_{ij}=tr(BA^\dagger)=tr(A^\dagger B)$$
It is easy to prove Frobenius inner product satisfy positivity, definiteness, conjugate symmetry, conjugate linearity in the first slot and linearity in the second slot, which is necessary for the definition of a inner product by applying the basic properties of trace.

Besides, we immediately find that Frobenius norm (Hilbert-Schmidt norm or Schatten 2-norm) has been derived:
$$\langle A, A\rangle_F=tr(A^\dagger A)= \|A\|_F^2$$

Now we can take a look at Cauchy-Schwarz inequality under this condition.

**Theorem.** For any $A, B \in C^{m\times n}$, always holds Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\|A\|_F \|B\|_F \geq |\langle A, B\rangle_F|$$
The inequality is saturated iff $A=cB$, where $c$ is an complex constant.

**Proof.**

Consider the Frobenius inner product $\langle A-\lambda I, A-\lambda I\rangle_F$. It's obviously that $\langle A-\lambda I, A-\lambda I\rangle_F \geq 0$.
\begin{align}
  \text{i.e.}&&\langle A-\lambda I, A-\lambda I\rangle&=tr[(A-\lambda I)^\dagger(A-\lambda I)]\\
  & & &=tr[A^\dagger A-\lambda A^\dagger B -\lambda^*B^\dagger A+|\lambda|^2 B^\dagger B]\\
  & & &=\|A\|_F^2+|\lambda|^2\|B\|_F^2-\lambda \langle A, B\rangle_F-\lambda^* \langle B, A\rangle_F \geq 0
\end{align}
Let $\lambda=\frac{\langle B, A\rangle_F }{\|B\|_F^2}$
\begin{align}
  |A\|_F^2+\frac{\langle B, A\rangle_F\langle B, A\rangle_F^*}{\|B\|_F^2}-\frac{\langle B, A\rangle_F\langle A, B\rangle_F}{\|B\|_F^2}-\frac{\langle B, A\rangle_F^*\langle B, A\rangle_F}{\|B\|_F^2} \geq 0
\end{align}
Then we can get
\begin{align}
\hspace{12em}&&\|A\|_F \|B\|_F \geq |\langle A, B\rangle_F| &&\hspace{12em}\square
\end{align}

**Lemma.** The nuclear norm of a matrix $T$ can be written as $\|T\|_*=\max\limits_{S^\dagger S=I} |tr(TS)|$.

**Proof.** For the sake of simplification, here we use Dirac (Bra-Ket) notation to prove this. (However, a proof by using matrix notation is equivalent.)

Suppose a matrix $T$ can be written as the form of SVD: $T=\sum\limits_j t_j |f_j\rangle\langle e_j|$ and a unitary matrix $S=\sum\limits_k |g_k\rangle\langle f_k|$, where $\{|e_j\rangle\}, \{|f_j\rangle\}, \{|g_j\rangle\}$ are orthonormal bases. $t_j\geq 0$ are singular values of $T$. So that
$$ST=\sum\limits_j t_j |f_j\rangle\langle e_j|$$
$$|tr(ST)|=|\sum\limits_j t_j \langle f_j|g_j \rangle|\leq \sum\limits_j t_j |\langle f_j|g_j \rangle|\leq \sum\limits_j t_j =\|T\|_*$$
The inequality is saturated iff $S=\sum\limits_k |e_k\rangle\langle f_k|$ as $\{|e_j\rangle\}, \{|f_j\rangle\}, \{|g_j\rangle\}$ are orthonormal bases.

Now we can derive the lemma that
\begin{align}
\hspace{8em}&&\|T\|_*=\max\limits_{S^\dagger S=I} |tr(ST)|=\max\limits_{S^\dagger S=I} |tr(TS)| &&\hspace{9em}\square
\end{align}

**Theorem.** Suppose A is a square matrix, then
$$ \left\| {\bf A}^2 \right\|_* \leq \operatorname{tr} \left( {\bf A}^\dagger {\bf A} \right)$$
where $\|\cdot\|_*$ denotes the nuclear norm (Schatten 1-norm).

**Proof.** It follows directly from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{align}
\|A^2\|_\ast=\max\limits_{S^\dagger S=I}|\operatorname{tr}(A^2S)|=\max\limits_{S^\dagger S=I}|\langle A^\dagger,AQ\rangle_F|\le\max\limits_{S^\dagger S=I}\|A^\dagger\|_F\|AQ\|_F=\|A\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger A)\quad\square
\end{align}

Besides, there is a corollary which can be derived by applying spectral theorem and the condition when Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is saturated.

**Corollary.**  The inequality $\| {\bf A}^2 \|_* \leq \operatorname{tr} \left( {\bf A}^\dagger {\bf A} \right)$ is saturated iff $A$ is normal.